# How do I use qmqtool to list emails from a specific envelope sender?

Tags: spam, email, queue

Occassionally a user's email password will become compromised and the spammer will flood the Qmail queue with 10,000+ emails sent through a specific user's account. I know how to use `qmqtool` to remove messages that match a specific string:

```
qmqtool -d -f "email@example.com"
```

However the `-f` argument matches anywhere in the message.

> -f 'STRING'     display comma separated list of message number(s) containing STRING.

That means messages to, from, and even mentioning that email address will all be deleted. Does `qmqtool` (or another qmail tool) have a command for matching messages from a specific envelope sender?

Note: I only want to match the authenticated sender, not the "From:" which is always forged in this case anyway.